# I am not able to install Wine package

Tags: apt, wine

When i type

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

pc config `lscpu`:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               42
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2120 CPU @ 
3.30GHz
Stepping:            7
CPU MHz:             1599.925
CPU max MHz:         3300.0000
CPU min MHz:         1600.0000
BogoMIPS:            6599.90
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 
apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
```

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-stable (and don't write in capital).

Comment: You have held packages, ie. it's likely your issue is prior command(s) that failed. Have you tried `sudo apt -f install`, and it's best if we're provided your release instead of guessing.  We can't look up possible issues until we have that information.

Comment: I USED BUT IT IS NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file should contain:

If you are using **18.04:**

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

If you are using **19.10:**

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
```

After source.list correction do

- `sudo apt clean && sudo apt update`.
- `sudo apt install wine`